# Argument of type 'typeof Bar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof BaseDataModel'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I realised after spending some time that if I don't put a constructor in the BaseDataModel, I will get an error in the last line

> Argument of type 'typeof Bar' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'typeof BaseDataModel'.

So my question is WHY a missing constructor in the Base class creates incompatibility ?

```
abstract class BaseDataModel {
    static fromJson<T>(json: any): T {
        return Object.assign(new this(), json);
    }

    constructor(obj?: any) {
    } //if you remove this constructor, you will get an error
}

class Foo extends BaseDataModel {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export class Bar extends BaseDataModel {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(obj: NonFunctionProperties<NewPostPayload>) {
        super()
        Object.assign(this, obj)
        this.title = obj.title
        this.content = obj.content


    }
    
}

function validateServerPayload(body: any, asdfasf: typeof BaseDataModel) {
    const payload = asdfasf.fromJson(body);
    validate(payload)
}

validateServerPayload({id: 1, name: 'foo'}, NewPostPayload);
validateServerPayload({id: 1, name: 'foo'}, Foo);
validateServerPayload({id: 1, name: 'foo'}, Bar); // error here
```

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Comment: What is NewPosPayload? What is NonFunctionProperties?

Comment: Because the `Bar` constructor has a different signature than the `BaseDataModel` constructor. It requires an object to construct it. You cannot create an object instance by calling an empty constructor. Did you try making obj as optional?

Comment: If `validateServerPayload` only needs something with a `fromJSON` method, write that, not `typeof BaseDataModel`